# Two dimensional binary index tree implementation using an auxiliary array

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, bit-manipulation

The binary index tree can be implemented in two dimension also. But unlike one dimensional implementation it requires an auxiliary array. What is the purpose of this auxilary array in this algorithm

The implementation is described in this [article](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/two-dimensional-binary-indexed-tree-or-fenwick-tree/)

```cpp
using namespace std;

#define N 4 // N-->max_x and max_y

struct Query
{
   int x1, y1; // x and y co-ordinates of bottom left
   int x2, y2; // x and y co-ordinates of top right
};


void updateBIT(int BIT[][N+1], int x, int y, int val)
{
   for (; x <= N; x += (x & -x))
   {
      for (; y <= N; y += (y & -y))
         BIT[x][y] += val;
   }
   return;
}

// A function to get sum from (0, 0) to (x, y)
int getSum(int BIT[][N+1], int x, int y)
{
   int sum = 0;

   for(; x > 0; x -= x&-x)
   {
      // This loop sum through all the 1D BIT
      // inside the array of 1D BIT = BIT[x]
      for(; y > 0; y -= y&-y)
      {
         sum += BIT[x][y];
      }
   }
   return sum;
}

void constructAux(int mat[][N], int aux[][N+1])
{
   // Initialise Auxiliary array to 0
   for (int i=0; i<=N; i++)
   for (int j=0; j<=N; j++)
   aux[i][j] = 0;

   // Construct the Auxiliary Matrix
   for (int j=1; j<=N; j++)
   for (int i=1; i<=N; i++)
   aux[i][j] = mat[N-j][i-1];

   return;
}

// A function to construct a 2D BIT
void construct2DBIT(int mat[][N], int BIT[][N+1])
{
   // Create an auxiliary matrix
   int aux[N+1][N+1];
   constructAux(mat, aux);

   // Initialise the BIT to 0
   for (int i=1; i<=N; i++)
   for (int j=1; j<=N; j++)
   BIT[i][j] = 0;

   for (int j=1; j<=N; j++)
   {
      for (int i=1; i<=N; i++)
      {
         // Creating a 2D-BIT using update function
         // everytime we/ encounter a value in the
         // input 2D-array
         int v1 = getSum(BIT, i, j);
         int v2 = getSum(BIT, i, j-1);
         int v3 = getSum(BIT, i-1, j-1);
         int v4 = getSum(BIT, i-1, j);

         // Assigning a value to a particular element
         // of 2D BIT
         updateBIT(BIT, i, j, aux[i][j]-(v1-v2-v4+v3));
      }
   }

   return;
}

// A function to answer the queries
void answerQueries(Query q[], int m, int BIT[][N+1])
{
   for (int i=0; i<m; i++)
   {
      int x1 = q[i].x1 + 1;
      int y1 = q[i].y1 + 1;
      int x2 = q[i].x2 + 1;
      int y2 = q[i].y2 + 1;

      int ans = getSum(BIT, x2, y2)-getSum(BIT, x2, y1-1)-
      getSum(BIT, x1-1, y2)+getSum(BIT, x1-1, y1-1);

      printf ("Query(%d, %d, %d, %d) = %d\n",
      q[i].x1, q[i].y1, q[i].x2, q[i].y2, ans);
   }
   return;
}

// Driver program
int main()
{
   int mat[N][N] = {{1, 2, 3, 4},
                    {5, 3, 8, 1},
                    {4, 6, 7, 5},
                    {2, 4, 8, 9}};

   // Create a 2D Binary Indexed Tree
   int BIT[N+1][N+1];
   construct2DBIT(mat, BIT);

   Query q[] = {{1, 1, 3, 2}, {2, 3, 3, 3}, {1, 1, 1, 1}};
   int m = sizeof(q)/sizeof(q[0]);

   answerQueries(q, m, BIT);

   return(0);
}
```

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: what is the role of auxilary array?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the purpose of this auxilary array in this algorithm?

The auxilary array is needed in this algorithm because they have used the origin as the leftside bottom of the matrix, it wouldn't be required if they would have used leftside top as the origin point.